# Excel if function failing

Tags: excel, function, math, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to do the following:

"Put a formula in D13 that will either Add Number 1, Number 2 and Number 3 or multiply them depending on what you put in D12. You should put in some sort of error message too if the user puts in something incorrect."

```
Number 1    18 - D9
Number 2    21 - D10
Number 3    16 - D11
Function    Multiply - D12
Answer  FALSE - D13
```

I HAVE ENTERED THIS FUNCTION IN D13:

```
=if(D12="Add",SUM (D9,D10,D11,if(D12="Multiply",D9*D10*D11,(D12="ERROR"))))
```

However, every-time I enter the function, it just says "FALSE"...

any help possible? Thanks

Comment: 1. You've simply misplaced a bracket. `=IF(D12="Add",SUM(D9:D11), IF(D12="Multiply", PRODUCT(D9:D11), "ERROR"))`. 2. You cannot change the value in D12 using a formula in D13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had a problem with setting the brackets and in output of "error message". Does this formula work?

```
=IF(D12="Add",SUM(D9,D10,D11),IF(D12="Multiply",D9*D10*D11,"ERROR"))
```